# FreeRADIUS and processing "Accounting - Request"

Tags: radius, freeradius

I've setup a radius server in our local network (using freeradius3), and now the clients are successfully login and send their accounting requests to the radius server.

What I need to accomplish is to pass the Accounting Requests (and their attributes) to an external program to process or filter some information. the external program however does not need to return anything to the radius server or change the normal workflow in the radius, so simply a copy of accounting requests has to be sent to the external program.

Couldn't find anything useful on web, so could you please point me to a tutorial or explain how would you implement that ?

Thank you

Comment: so, is it reasonable to use 'update request' block to do this ?

Comment: No, that will cause the worker thread to block and wait for the program to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [exec module config](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.1.x/raddb/mods-available/exec).  The key thing is to set wait to `no` this means FreeRADIUS will not wait for the program to return.

You can then use the exec module instance as detailed in the header of that file i.e.

```
"%{exec:<path to program> '%{<attribute>}' '%{<attribute>}'}"
```